# Transformation of inner function in javascript (bind())

Tags: javascript

Having some problem extracting inner functions in javascript. Consider the following function:

```
this.zoomListener = d3.zoom()
    .on("zoom", (function(){
        new_xScale = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(this.xScale)
        new_yScale = d3.event.transform.rescaleY(this.yScale)
    }).bind(this));
```

To be a little more flexible i wanted to change the structur of the inner function like this:

```
this.zoomListener = d3.zoom()
        .on("zoom", zoomFunction);

function zoomFunction(){
            new_xScale = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(this.xScale)
            new_yScale = d3.event.transform.rescaleY(this.yScale)
        }
```

How can i bind the function now?

Comment: @Rajesh: Not really a dupe, as the lexical context is quite different. OP obviously knew how to access the correct `this` as they used `bind`.

Comment: @Amadan In my understanding, issue is that OP us sending a callback and is expecting it to have same context. So, in my understanding this was the appropriate dupe. Please share the appropriate one and I'll pull back my vote.

Answer (score -1):

```
.on("zoom", zoomFunction.bind(this));
```

You can just use `bind` on the variable itself. `bind` just wants a function value, and it doesn't matter if you attach it to a function expression or to a variable that contains a function, it will do the same thing.

Comment: Done sir. Also, please do not get offended. Apologies, if I was rude. Its just, I expect people like us to maintain discipline and lead by example.

Comment: I have a bit stricter definition of dupe than most, I suppose. That wasn't one.

Comment: Sorry for asking a question that was already asked. Nevertheless thank you for the answer.

Comment: @DerMann No need to apologies for asking a dupe. Its a normal thing. I just hope it helps you resolve your issue.